# How do I loop over items 1 by 1 in Ansible config (YAML/Jinja2)?

Tags: python, ansible, yaml

I am trying to loop over my hosts from my inventory in Ansible, and use the name of the host of that iteration in a command. In particular, I am trying to set the hostname of each of my hosts to whatever I have called them in my hosts file. So, I have web01, web02, web03 etc for my webservers -- I want to set these as hostnames on the servers in each question, i.e. I want to loop over "all" hosts and when I'm on web01 (first iteration), I want to pass that name of the host I am on to the hostname module. This is what I tried:

```
- hosts: all
become: true
tasks:
  - hostname:
      name: "{{ item }}"
    with_items: "{{ play_hosts }}"
```

However, instead of setting as hostname the name of the host I am on, this tries to set every single host from my ansible config as hostname on each single server. So it tries to do:

```
connect to web01; hostname -> web01; hostname -> web02; hostname -> web03
connect to web02; hostname -> web01; hostname -> web02; hostname -> web03
connect to web03; hostname -> web01; hostname -> web02; hostname -> web03
```

Instead I want:

```
connect to web01; hostname -> web01
connect to web02; hostname -> web02
connect to web03; hostname -> web03
```

How can I do that?

I found a similar question here: [Ansible: setting hostname over inventory](https://serverfault.com/questions/666330/ansible-setting-hostname-over-inventory)

but this was answered with a more complicated solution than I am hoping for. The suggestion there was to add suffixes, but surely a simple loop like I want shouldn't require that in principle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to loop over hosts, as this is one of the most fundamental Ansible functions (it is disabled on a few selected modules, but `hostname` is not one of them).

To set the target machine's hostname to the value defined in the Ansible inventory file, all you need to do, is to reference the `inventory_hostname` variable (see [Magic Variables](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_variables.html#magic-variables-and-how-to-access-information-about-other-hosts)):

```
- hosts: all
  become: true
  tasks:
    - hostname:
        name: "{{ inventory_hostname }}"
```